# Huawei Map Kit - onMapReady() not called after getMapAsync()

Tags: android, maps, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to create a huawei variant of a locator feature of a project that uses google maps. But my problem is that onMapReady() callback does not trigger at all after getMapAsync()

This is how i call getMapAsync:

```
     val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_huawei_map_container) as SupportMapFragment
     mapFragment.getMapAsync(this@SampleMapsFragment)
```

This works fine when using google maps depedencies as onMapReady() is getting called.

But when using huawei map dependencies, onMapReady callback does not trigger at all after getMapAsync()

Comment: Do you enable MapKit in console? Do you check SHA-256 in console?

Comment: I double checked right now to be sure and yes I already put SHA-256 and enabled mapkit in the console.

Comment: Do you test on Huawei device? Maps only work on Huawei devices

Comment: I have a non huawei device but a workaround I did is to install hms core apk

Comment: Yes, as I can see in [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-sdk-version-change-history-0000001050156688-V5), latest version of MapKit doesn't require Huawei device, if you have latest HmsCore app and OS>=7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the Huawei's map kit to do these please check the following:
You have generated a sha256 key and integrated HMS core, you can use this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html#0) to find out how.

If you have done all the above, make sure that agconnect-services.json is in the right place. Then, check if in your manifest you have:
[image]

A final thing to check is that if you have done
[image]

I hope one of these will help as I was able to get onMapReady to trigger:

[image]

Comment: I can display the maps now when calling inside the onViewCreated of the fragment. But I have a new problem when calling getMapAsync inside location callback

Comment: Glad your problem is resolved. What's your new problem?

Comment: check my update on my post. It's when getMapAsync is called inside a LocationCallback

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look tomorrow when I have time. But fairly speaking, if your previous problem got resolved, you should give people the credit they deserve.

Comment: i removed the update. I'll just post a new question since this is a different problem. Thanks for helping btw

Answer (score 1):

The **onMapReady** method needs to be reloaded. The following describes how to create a map instance using [SupportMapFragment](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/supportmapfragment-0000001050153243-V5). For more details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-map-instance-creation-0000001062881706).

1. Add a **Fragment** object in the layout file (for example, **activity_main.xml**), and set map attributes in the file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment_mapfragmentdemo"
    class="com.huawei.hms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraTargetLat="48.893478"
    map:cameraTargetLng="2.334595"
    map:cameraZoom="10" />
```

2. To use a map in your app, implement the [OnMapReadyCallback](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/onmapreadycallback-0000001050150378-V5) API in the **MainActivity.java** file.
   The sample code is as follows:

```
public class SupportMapDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    ...
}
```

3. In the **MainActivity.java** file, load [SupportMapFragment](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/supportmapfragment-0000001050153243-V5) in the **onCreate()** method and call [getMapAsync()](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mapfragment-0000001050150294-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050150294__section11704105017376) to register the callback.
   The sample code is as follows:

```
private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment; 
mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment_mapfragmentdemo);
mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

4. Call the [onMapReady](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/onmapreadycallback-0000001050150378-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050150378__section74342919481) callback to obtain the [HuaweiMap](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/huaweimap-0000001050151757-V5) object.
   The sample code is as follows:

```
public void onMapReady(HuaweiMap huaweiMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: ");     
    hMap = huaweiMap;
}
```

5. Run your project and then install your app to view the map in your app.

Comment: You've just copy pasted the ones in the docs. Thanks anyway