# HMS Map toolkit - onMapReady() not called after getMapAsync() calling

Tags: android, maps, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I am working with HMS Maps, for this I follow their documentation.
For this query I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608570/huawei-map-kit-onmapready-not-called-after-getmapasync/65638635). I added SHA-256 key and agconnect-services.json file too.
The Steps which I did are:

dependency in app gradle: `implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:6.0.0.301'`
in app gradle: `apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'`

My root gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }

        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }

    }
}
```

I added SHA-256 key at AppGallery connect.
Enabled MapApi from AppGallery connect.
Downloaded and added "agconnect-services.json" file in my project.

After resolving some thread related issues, I am able to produce logcat errors and it is saying that "Illegal FingerPrint".
I know, it is about some integration issues with the AppGallery but I am unable to get it that what I am missing, I am following all the steps.
**Logcat is:**

```
2021-08-31 10:35:22.520 30490-30773/com.moody.poster E/HmsMapKit_AuthenticateClient_1074: Exception occur
    com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.d: *1*0*2*:*I*L*G*L*F*N*E*P*I*T
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.d$d.c(:89)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.c.d(:22556)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.c.c(:88)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.client.auth.e.d(:76)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.client.auth.e.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.client.auth.b.a(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.c$a.e(:492)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.client.auth.e.c(:1074)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.cache.c$b.e(:298)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.cache.c$b.call(:291)
        at eU.a(:42)
        at em.d(:12025)
        at fc$b.run(:96)
        at eq$c.run(:571)
        at fj.run(:66)
        at fj.call(:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
2021-08-31 10:35:22.528 30490-30773/com.moody.poster E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_509: cache error trace log : ErrorTraceLogDTO{ scenario = ACCESS_SERVICE_ERROR', message='010002 : ILLEGAL_FINGERPRINT'}
    com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.d: *1*0*2*:*I*L*G*L*F*N*E*P*I*T
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.d$d.c(:89)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.c.d(:22556)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.c.c(:88)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.client.auth.e.d(:76)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.client.auth.e.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.client.auth.b.a(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.foundation.client.c$a.e(:492)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.client.auth.e.c(:1074)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.cache.c$b.e(:298)
        at com.huawei.hms.maps.maproute.cache.c$b.call(:291)
        at eU.a(:42)
        at em.d(:12025)
        at fc$b.run(:96)
        at eq$c.run(:571)
        at fj.run(:66)
        at fj.call(:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
2021-08-31 10:35:22.536 30490-30773/com.moody.poster E/HmsMapKit_AuthenticateCache_333: other err occur,errorCode ： .010002 : ILLEGAL_FINGERPRINT
2021-08-31 10:35:22.775 30490-30490/com.moody.poster E/HmsMapKit_AccessTraceLogPusher_16: analyticsInstance is null
2021-08-31 10:35:22.778 30490-30490/com.moody.poster E/HmsMapKit_UserEventLogPusher_16: analyticsInstance is null
```

Comment: hi@Faizan, may i ask does your map show? And could you pls post the code of the map display class?

Comment: No, my map is not loading, after calling "getMapAsync(this)" function, I am unable to get "onMapReady(HuaweiMap huaweiMap)" callback function.

Comment: hi@Faizan, Could you pls provide the error log of the map kit for us to check this issue?

Comment: There were some thread issues, after resolving that I am able to produce logcat errors.

My issue is about some integration with AppGallery (Illegal Fingerprint)
I am updating my question, please review it. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: since version 'com.huawei.hms:maps:6.5.0.301',  'MapsInitializer.initialize(this)' is needed before setting the api key to use Huaweii map kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that why it is happening, I talked to Huawei developers regarding this issue, I was doing this in a fragment but when I tried this in an activity, it works perfectly. Now I am doing it in a separate Activity. (I created that activity with the built in method of HMS toolkit.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once when I was implementing HMS Map. In my case it was that I had the map on a fragment and was using the activity documentation. To fix it I had to use the SupportMapFragment and everything worked correctly after that.

Comment: I am already using SupportMapFragment, Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

In your following log:

> 2021-08-31 10:35:22.528 30490-30773/com.moody.poster E/HmsMapKit_ErrorTraceLogPusher_509: cache error trace log : ErrorTraceLogDTO{ scenario = ACCESS_SERVICE_ERROR', message='010002 : ILLEGAL_FINGERPRINT'}

As [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/faq-0000001050166999#section1817194262911) mentioned, The possible causes are as follows:

- The app ID in your project is different from that in AppGallery Connect.
- No signing certificate fingerprint is configured. You need to generate a signing certificate fingerprint and configure it in AppGallery Connect.
- The AppGallery Connect configuration file of your app is not configured. You need to follow instructions in [Adding the AppGallery Connect Configuration File of Your App](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-integrating-sdk-0000001061671869#section4256162815361) to configure it.
- The API key is not transcoded using **encode**.

Also you can follow this Docs: [Generating a Signing Certificate Fingerprint](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-config-agc-0000001061560289#section147011294331), see if there's a problem.

---

The following [Map kit codelab](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSMapKit/index.html#5) is for your reference. You could follow this to see if its works.

1.Declare relevant permissions in blocks at the same level as the application block in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

2.Add MapView to the layout file. The file path is `\mapdemo\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
    
    <com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView  
       xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
        android:id="@+id/mapView" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        map:cameraTargetLat="51" 
        map:cameraTargetLng="10" 
        map:cameraZoom="8.5" 
        map:mapType="normal" 
        map:uiCompass="true" 
        map:uiZoomControls="true" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

3.Add the configuration for calling MapView to the activity file. The file path is `\mapdemo\app\src\main\java\com\wz\android\mapdemo\MainActivity.java`.

```
package com.wz.android.mapdemo; 
 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log; 
 
import com.huawei.hms.maps.HuaweiMap; 
import com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView; 
import com.huawei.hms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback; 
 
/** 
* Map activity entrance class. 
*/ 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback { 
 
    private static final String TAG = "MapViewDemoActivity"; 
    // Huawei map. 
    private HuaweiMap hMap; 
 
    private MapView mMapView; 
 
    private static final String MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey"; 
 
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        // Obtain a MapView instance. 
        mMapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null; 
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { 
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY); 
        } 
 
        // Please replace Your API key with the API key in  
        // agconnect-services.json. 
        MapsInitializer.setApiKey("Your API key"); 
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle); 
        // Obtain a map instance. 
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this); 
    } 
 
    @Override 
    public void onMapReady(HuaweiMap map) { 
        // Obtain a map instance from callback. 
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: "); 
        hMap = map; 
    } 
}
```

4.Add the lifecycle methods of MapView. The file path is `\mapdemo\app\src\main\java\com\wz\android\mapdemo\MainActivity.java`.

```
@Override 
protected void onStart() { 
    super.onStart(); 
    mMapView.onStart(); 
} 
 
@Override 
protected void onStop() { 
    super.onStop(); 
    mMapView.onStop(); 
} 
 
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() { 
    super.onDestroy(); 
    mMapView.onDestroy(); 
} 
 
@Override 
protected void onPause() { 
    mMapView.onPause(); 
    super.onPause(); 
} 
 
@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
    mMapView.onResume(); 
}
```

5.Verify that required permissions have been assigned. The file path is `\mapdemo\app\src\main\java\com\wz\android\mapdemo\MainActivity.java`.

```
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) { 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && permissions != null) { 
        for (String permission : permissions) { 
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question with logcat errors. Please have a look on it.
It is about some integration. But I am not able to trace it.

Comment: hi@Faizan, i updated my answer above, pls refer that.

Comment: I am unable to get the issue. I was trying it in a fragment and it was giving me "ILLEGAL_FINGERPRINT" that means app's configuration with AppGallery was not correct.
Now I am trying it in an Activity and it is working fine. If there is an "ILLEGAL_FINGERPRINT" issue then it should also effect on Activity.

But now, with Activity, it is working fine, don't know what was the issue.

By the way, Thanks for your support.

Comment: Glad to hear that the issue has been resolved.please feel free to contact me if you need any further help. 

Comment: yup but I have a question, why it is not working on fragment, why it is saying "ILLEGAL_FINGERPRINT"?

Comment: That's weird. Maybe you can post the code of your fragment and let me check.

Comment: Can you please send me your email so that I can send you my code on that email.

Comment: sorry@Faizan,could you mind post it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and tag with [huawei-mobile-services] for us to trace this issue? Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.